# Router update Local IP instead of Public IP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, local

I have TP-Link MR3220, and I'm using it as router. I installed the DYNdns information correctly and reboot and when I check again with the updated IP, it shows that updated IP is 192.168.1.5 which is my router IP. Instead of updating the public IP, the ddns client on the router update the IP as local IP. Please show me how do I get the DDClient update my public IP instead of local IP. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it appears that you're using the incorrect setting in the "use" line.

Change "use=if,if=eth0" to "use=web" and restart ddclient.  It should update DYNdns with your external IP address.